# Windows Temp Files Shredding Tool

Tags: windows, browser, file-management

I need a tool to clean and shred temp files from any browser session. I have tried eraser but is there a better tool out there that requires less manual job scheduling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/). It allows you to choose how many times to overwrite the files it deletes.

Comment: I vote +1 to CCleaner

Comment: Another vote for CCleaner. You can use the built in options to have it run when you log in, etc, and I am also pretty sure you can run it from the command line (for the purposes of scheduling a task). Not sure on the last one however.

Comment: Dan's right. Go to Options > Settings, and you should have options for Normal File Deletion, and Secure File Deletion, which includes options for DOD (3 passes), Gutmann (35 passes), and NSA (7 passes).

Answer (score 1):

Use IE8 with [inprivate browsing](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/08/25/ie8-and-privacy.aspx) (AKA Porn mode)

Comment: Just don't forget about this: http://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-stori

Answer (score 0):

You could download [SDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) and run a [Scheduled Tasks](https://superuser.com/questions/6490/windows-equivalent-to-cron) at a regular interval to delete the temp browser files.