# Run script on Windows every n minutes

Tags: windows, script, scheduled-tasks

What's the best way on a Windows machine to run some sort of script every n minutes?

I've googled around and read that Windows Scheduler is best avoided.

Comment: You might want to say why you think Windows Scheduler isn't appropriate for you.

Comment: The only answer I really have to that is based on my googling. I've read that Windows Scheduler is unreliable. I may be off the mark?

Comment: @Jamie - can you add a link or two to the information you've found. I've never had problems with Windows Scheduled Tasks, so I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be helpful if you say what the problems are with Windows scheduler - It works **VERY** well and I would use it.

Simply go in to Task Scheduler / Scheduled Tasks and set up a new one, It is very easy to set and use.

If you say what version of Windows you are you using, I can post some pictures and further help.

Answer (score 1):

The free [System scheduler](http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm) from Splinterware can do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not satisfied with the GUI based task scheduler, `schtasks.exe` allows command-line finely controlled access to the Windows task scheduling framework. Excellent documentation is available on the Microsoft website:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/schtasks